# Unable to write from spark pool to sql pool in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure-synapse

I have a table in the default spark pool which i need to load into the dedicated sql pool in the azure synapse. Below are the codes I implemented, however it is not loading.

```
%%pyspark
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")
new_df = spark.createDataFrame(segmentation_output)
new_df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("default.segmentation_output")


%%pyspark
new_df.createOrReplaceTempView("pysparkdftemptable")


%%spark
val scala_df = spark.sqlContext.sql ("select * from pysparkdftemptable")
scala_df.write.synapsesql("eana.bi.xim_CustomerSegment", Constants.INTERNAL)



Error : StructuredStream-spark package version: 2.4.5-1.3.1
StructuredStream-spark package version: 2.4.5-1.3.1
StructuredStream-spark package version: 2.4.5-1.3.1
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host eec8e890e9d5--0.tr624.northeurope1-a.worker.database.windows.net (redirected from emna-dv-ibsanalytics-wco-id-euno-sqs.database.windows.net), port 11030 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```